# What are the names of these aircraft? Part.2

Tags: aircraft-identification

The next part of the group... Can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would it be better to ask a separate question about each plane? That way each will (hopefully) have a single definitive answer.

Comment: Yes, please do make these one question per model. (Though if you have multiple pictures that you believe represent the same type of aircraft, it probably won't hurt including all of those in a question for that model.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third one looks like a Boeing model 203

[image]

([source](http://www.boeingimages.com/archive/Model-203-at-Boeing-School-of-Aeronautics-2F3XC5FVY6M.html))

Second one is an Avro Type D

[image: avro type d]

([source](http://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft28550.htm))

Fourth one is a fictive one, inspired by a Macchi M33 with swept parasol wing version. (famously known to be Porco Rosso's plane in eponym Miyazaki animated movie)

[image: macchi m33]

([source](http://www.aeronautica.difesa.it/mezzi/mstorici/Pagine/MACCHI-M33.aspx))

Answer (score 4):

The last one is an [Antinov AN-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-2)

[image]

([source](http://www.warbirdsonline.com.au/2014/01/22/antonov-an-2-australias-colt/))

The first one could be the [Gee Bee Y Sportster](https://www.fantasyofflight.com/collection/aircraft/currently-not-showing-in-museum/golden-age/1931-gee-bee-y-sportster/)

[image]

([source](https://www.fantasyofflight.com/collection/aircraft/currently-not-showing-in-museum/golden-age/1931-gee-bee-y-sportster/))

Comment: Concur on the Antonov, but the shape of both the tail & the engine cowling is pretty different from the Gee Bee’s.

Comment: @RalphJ I agree the models tail is pointier and the Gee Bee has a cowling enclosure but I have built models that are not always exactly accurate so it was just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

First one may be a [Ryan PT22 trainer](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.warbirdalley.com/images/PT-22-aerial-01-comp.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.warbirdalley.com/pt22.htm&h=1147&w=1696&tbnid=hsPT0MiQStfWVM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=236&usg=__ZgIgN0cZExmcy5k6MmSmPtd2MnY%3D&vet=10ahUKEwjHsozIr73ZAhUKulMKHQtQAdoQ_B0IiAEwDg..i&docid=5V03xunuxzn9TM&itg=1&client=safari&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHsozIr73ZAhUKulMKHQtQAdoQ_B0IiAEwDg), used for basic pilot instruction in WW2 by the USAAF and USN. Those flying today tend to be turned out in polished aluminum with yellow wings, the original colors of the trainers. Not long ago, Harrison Ford deadsticked a PT22 onto a golf course when it's engine quit.

Third one looks like an earlier [Travel Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_Air), maybe a model 4000, fitted with wing spotlights for air mail service. Travel Air was the original company of three light plane legends: Clyde Cessna, Walter Beech, and Lloyd Stearman.